# HttpsURLConnection.getErrorStream doesn't give as much output as putting the url in a browser

Tags: java, https

I'm writing a java program to send an http request to a URL. I don't have the required authentication, and the response is a code 500. I'm accessing con.getErrorStream() to get the response message, which just says 'An error has occurred'.
However if I put the same url in my Chrome browser address bar, it shows an XML response which has the same error message, but a lot more information as well.
How can I get the full response in java code?

I have looked at the javadoc for HttpsURLConnection, and tried all the methods that might give additional response, e.g. getContet().

```java
public static String getQueryResponse(String queryPath) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(TALENT_URL+queryPath);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setUseCaches(false);

        int status = con.getResponseCode();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        if(status > 299)
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()));
        else
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String resp = "Response message: " + con.getResponseMessage() + "\n";
        try {
            Object content = con.getContent();
            System.out.println(content.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error getting content: "+ e.getMessage());
        }
        resp += reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        con.disconnect();
        return resp;
    }
```

The code above gives the output:
Error getting content: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: (url redacted)
Response message: Internal Server Error
{"Message":"An error has occurred."}

If I put the same url in the Chrome address bar, I get:

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>Forbidden</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
System.ServiceModel.Web.WebFaultException`1[[System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Services.ServicesSessionProvider.ThrowSessionCreationException(ServicesSessionCreationErrorCode exceptionCode) at Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Services.ServicesSessionProvider.GetSession(Boolean isILSession, Boolean bypassAuthentication, WorkLoadTypeEnum workLoadType, String issuer, String company, String language, String partitionKey, ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity) at Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Services.ServicesSessionManager.InitThreadSession(Boolean ilSession, SessionType sessionType, Boolean bypassAuthentication, String authIssuer, String company, String language, String partitionKey, ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity) at Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Common.SessionManagement.ServicesAosSessionManager.InitializeSession(SessionType sessionType, Boolean bypassAuthentication, String authIssuerThumbprint, ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity) at Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Common.SessionManagement.OwinRequestSessionProvider.CreateSession(ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity) at Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Common.SessionManagement.ServicesRequestSessionHelper.EnsureRequestSession(IServicesRequestSessionProvider servicesRequestSessionProvider, ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity) at Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Common.SessionManagement.EnsureServicesRequestSessionHandler.EnsureServicesRequestSession(HttpRequestMessage request, IApplicationEnvironment applicationEnvironment)
</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

How is it that the browser shows more than I can get programatically? Is there a way to get this fuller response in java code?

Comment: What if you read from the input stream even if there's an error?

Comment: These are different errors. One is 500, the other is 403 or similar.

Comment: Your code is not making exactly the same HTTP request as the browser.  The browser is sending a number of headers;  I wouldn’t be surprised if the `User-Agent` header determines the type of error response you receive.  The `Accept` header probably matters here too.  You probably want to duplicate as many browser request headers as you can in your code.

Comment: user207421 you are right, in the browser the response code is 403

Comment: VGR you are right, the headers make a big difference. I haven't managed to duplicate the browser response, but I've certainly got some very different responses by adding different headers. Thanks.